# How does STYLY Gallery work to load 3d objects?

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, webgl

I was wondering how STYLY Gallery handles many 3d models and show them individually like [here](https://gallery.styly.cc/scene/8c54733e-7e04-4601-9659-5b2642add3f5)

I found a fantastic library ([React Unity WebGL](https://github.com/jeffreylanters/react-unity-webgl)) that enables embedding Unity build into React application and I suppose STYLY also uses it.

But I don't know how they manage multiple 3d objects in one place and display them depending on user interaction.

Does anyone know or have any idea about it?

Do I need to build every 3d object for each page like the link above?
Or just switch/loading different scenes in Unity build would be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe loaded when you start the web player is https://build.styly.cc/player/release/?8c54733e-7e04-4601-9659-5b2642add3f5; the UUID in the URL is the scene ID from your original link.

Looking at the dev tools for the iframe, it's doing a couple of API requests, one of which is for https://api.styly.cc/api/v2/scene/8c54733e-7e04-4601-9659-5b2642add3f5/content. That URL seems to describe an XML document that has references to assets that are loaded from a CDN.

Looking at the binary data loaded, it seems to be some Unity-specific format:

```
$ xxd ba158aaf-95e4-4e09-96ff-3567538742ca
00000000: 556e 6974 7946 5300 0000 0006 352e 782e  UnityFS.....5.x.
00000010: 7800 3230 3139 2e33 2e36 6631 0000 0000  x.2019.3.6f1....
00000020: 0000 003d 3d00 0000 4100 0000 5b00 0000  ...==...A...[...
00000030: 431e 0001 00b1 0100 0100 2800 003c cb00  C.........(..<..
```

I assume the Unity Web Player can load that format into objects and place them into the scene based on the `content` specification.

So:

No, you do not need to build a separate player for each page, but it looks like a nontrivial amount of work has gone into this on Styly's end to make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

I see so they fetch unity webGL data through API depending on id like URL, rather than create unity webGL build for each object uploaded right?

So if the object choices are limited to like 10 then building 10 unity app and puting them in react public folder and then use them according the state variable would be good enough?

Comment: Seems like that's the case.

Comment: Sorry I added comment! So could you please check it too?

Comment: If you have a small number of models, then I suppose building separate apps would be good enough to start with, and of course you can always change things later if the approach doesn't scale.